# How to access a variable from a javascript file in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to write a project in typescript, but I am using a javascript library, I am wondering how to use the variable in the javascript library in my typescript project. Below is the specifics:

I have 3 files: the js library: `index.js`, the typescript files: `simulator.ts`, and the html file: `simulator.html`

In my `index.js`, I want to access the variable `ctx`, which was declared as:

```
var car_no = 10;
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

In my `simulator.html`, I have loaded the two files in the following order but it cannot be changed as the project environment requires the `sim.js` which is generated automatically from `simulator.ts` by the project environment to be loaded in `<head>`, and the `index.js` to be loaded in `<body>`. The codes are followings:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-manifest="" data-framework="typescript">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>sample simulator</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sim/public/sim.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="TrafficSimulation/css/style.css">
    <style>
        body {
            background: transparent;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>            
    <script language="javascript">
        window.onload = function(){ 
            var tag = document.createElement("script");
            tag.setAttribute("src", "TrafficSimulation/js/index.js");
            document.getElementById("svgcanvas").appendChild(tag);
        }
    </script>
    <script src="/cdn/bluebird.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/cdn/pxtsim.js"></script>
    <script src="/sim/sim.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="TrafficSimulation/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>        
    <div id="svgcanvas" style="height: 270;">
        <canvas></canvas>
        <div class="box">
            Number of Cars:<br>
            <br><input type="range" max="100" min="10" value="36" onChange="init();">
                <span class="car_no">10</span>
        </div>                   
    </div>        
</body>
```

what should I do in my simulator.ts to access the variables, functions, and etc from the js library?

Comment: In which file the following lines defined - `var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");`?

Comment: @jaibatrik in index.js

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to use the `ctx` variable in `simulator.ts`, you need to declare it globally. The syntax to declare would be -

```
declare let ctx: any;
```

Comment: in which file should I declare the variable?

Comment: does the order of loading sim.js and index.js matter?

Comment: I am wondering if the sim.js is loaded first, the index.js is loaded afterwards in simulator.html, the variables in the index.js are not loaded into the html file yet when sim.js is trying to get the references of the variables in index.js

Answer (score 0):

Many JS libraries will provide a TypeScript declaration file.

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html

If none is provide you may have to roll your own in order to get your editor to play nice.

Other notes:

- You may want to consider moving the jquery reference to the end of
  the body tag instead of inside the div.
- if any of the js is dependent on jquery, i'd move it to the end of
  the body tag below jquery as well.
- I think you have a extra closing style tag
- look at using JQuery.Ready() if you aren't already. Your js may be running before the canvas is in the DOM